# When to change signs in inequalities

Tags: inequality

Given the inequalities $-1 \le \frac{1}{x} \le 1,\;1 - \arccos(x) \gt 0$, I have noticed that in both, we have to change the signs. In this first one I can understand why, even we didn't change it we would quickly realize the solution would be impossible, however, in the second case it isn't as obvious, I reached the conclusion that $x$ would be $x \lt \cos(1)$ but it is the opposite, what is the reasoning of this? Also, in which cases should we be cautious that a change of sign could happen?

Comment: Inverting division by multiplication is _not at all like_ inverting $\cos$ using $\arccos$.

Comment: cosine is not monotone. so one has to know more about the sides of an inequality before finding the relation between the cosines of the sides.

Comment: It will not have inequality. Although it will have solution $x\in \mathbb{R}-\{2n\pi\}∀n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I apologize if the question sounded dumb, the real question was "Determine the domain of the function $ln(1 - arccos(x))$". From which I got $x \in [-1, 1]$ and $1 - arccos(x) > 0$. The solution that was provided was that $cos(1) \lt x \le 1$ which is why I made the assumption there should be a change of sings which I had trouble understanding, but thanks to @GregMartin I figured out why a change of sign would happen, even though it is not related to the first inequality I provided

Answer (score 3):

If we have an equality $A=B$, and we apply any function $f(x)$ to both sides, the result will also be an equality $f(A)=f(B)$ (by the definition of a function).

However, if we have an inequality $A\ge B$, then most functions won't have the property that $f(A)\ge f(B)$ always. There are two types of functions that we can say something predictable about:

- If $f(x)$ is an *increasing* function on some domain containing $A$ and $B$, then $A\ge B$ implies $f(A)\ge f(B)$. This includes adding a constant to both sides, multiplying both sides by a positive constant, taking square roots, and so on.
- If $f(x)$ is a *decreasing* function on some domain containing $A$ and $B$, then $A\ge B$ implies $f(A)\le f(B)$. This includes taking reciprocals, multiplying both sides by a negative constant, and even things like $\arccos$.

Moral of the story: once we understand fundamentally why certain common operations preserve or reverse inequalities, that allows us to decide when uncommon operations do or don't respect inequalities.